# Trouble with including .c file in XCode iOS project

Tags: ios, c, xcode

I have a `.c` file in my project that I would like to utilize; for the example, lets call it `MyCFile.c`. I have created a header file so that I can access the functions inside `MyCFile.c` named `MyCFile.h` and I've included the headers to the files like so:

```
#ifndef MyCFile_h
#define MyCFile_h

#import <Foundation/NSArray.h>

NSArray *myFunction();

#endif
```

But when I include the `.h` in another file inside my project, it complains saying that `Apple Mach-O Linker Error "_myFunction", referenced from: ... symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7` (armv7 being the device I'm testing on).

I've added the `.c` to my project through `Target Membership` and I've wrapped all Objective-C code in `#ifdef __OBJC__ ... #endif`.

What do I need to do in order to use my `.c` file in my other files?

Comment: do you get compile errors, when you put an error into the myFunction()?  I.e. making sure it is compiled with the project (and not for whatever reason excluded).

Comment: @QSQ Odd. I don't, even though `MyCFile.c` is listed under the `Compile Sources` in my `Build Phases`. It's also a target. I'm not sure what else to do..

Comment: It is ifdef'd somehow?

Comment: Also, did you try a build clean?

Comment: @QSQ It is `#ifdef`ed. Check the question for details. However, removing that doesn't add compile errors. And I've tried cleaning and cleaning the build folder, but nothing helps.

Comment: I did read that, but that's the .h file and that one s in order or you would get a compile error (not a link error).   I mean, is the .c source ifdefd (with #if __OBJC__).  Also, is the rest of your project objective-c or objective-c++ ?

Comment: @QSQ Please note the "I've added the `.c` to my project through `Target Membership` and I've wrapped all Objective-C code in `#ifdef __OBJC__ ... #endif`" in my question. Also, the rest is just Objective-C.

Comment: Well, in a source file of type of C-Source () #ifdef objc will never trigger (everything in #ifdef objc is just as good as not there).  If your missing function is inside such a block that would explain it.

Comment: @QSQ Look in the comments above. I've mentioned that removing the block, cleaning and building doesn't change anything.

Comment: I'm running out of ideas then.  My last idea would be to clear the .c source file completely (delete everything), and just write one line of gibberish there, to see if that gives a compile error (ie  it's not something that carried over from an #include file).

Comment: @QSQ I've just `Analyzed` the project and I'm getting this: `warning: no rule to process file '/My/Path/To/File/MyCFile.c' of type sourcecode.c for architecture armv7`.

Comment: Google "warning no rule to process file of type" there are a ton of search results for similar warnings (e.g. this result http://joytek.blogspot.tw/2011/09/xcode-4-warning-no-rule-to-process-file.html).

Comment: @QSQ Yes, however we've been over all of that. There aren't any `.h` files in my `Compile Sources` and the `.c` is in there as well. The targets are setup properly, too.

Comment: If you look at this blog post: http://joytek.blogspot.tw/2011/09/xcode-4-warning-no-rule-to-process-file.html.  In the 2nd screenshot, where the circle #4 is, next to Build-Phases, is "Build Rules."  There should be a rule "System C Rule" (the way I understand your Analyzer warnings is, that in those Build-Rules is no rule how to deal with a "C Source" file)

Comment: @QSQ The rule is there, unfortunately. I don't think there is anything to do at this point. I've attached C files to my iOS projects before and never had an issue. I've even tried deleting the file and moving the contents to a new one, but still no luck. I will just have to work around the issue.

Comment: I understand.  My last attempt (although this is merely a workaround) would be to change the file type to C-ObjectiveC like your other source files). Good luck.

Comment: @QSQ Yeah. That's what I will end up having to do. Thank you for all of the help. So, technically that's the answer, if you'd like some points.

Comment: No worries about the points. I was doing this because I like riddles/puzzles.  Thanks for the interaction.